# Does epoll have thread-safe issues?

Tags: multithreading, epoll

This is a follow-on to question 14221339.

I have a thread pool that is running inside an `epoll_wait()` loop.

An external thread calls `epoll_ctl()` and adds a listener socket with

`(EPOLLET | EPOLLONESHOT | EPOLLIN)`.

When the thread pool only has a single thread, it intermittently fails to receive an `EPOLLIN` event for the first (and only) connection attempt.  If I increase the thread pool to two, it almost always fails to receive an `EPOLLIN` event.

My understanding is that the epoll API is thread-safe, but this observation would seem to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

With edge-triggered semantics, an incorrect sequence of calls can result in a race condition.  There are three system calls involved:

1. epoll_ctl() to activate notifications (and reactivate if
   EPOLLONESHOT is used).
2. epoll_wait() to receive notifications.
3. system input: read()/recv()/accept() in a loop until error EAGAIN.

If executed (repeatedly) in this order, a race between #3 and #1 is possible: when the input event in the kernel occurs after EAGAIN has been returned but before epoll_ctl() can be acted on.  In general, the re-activation needs to be done before the I/O.

1. epoll_ctl() to activate notifications (and reactivate if
   EPOLLONESHOT is used).
2. system input: read()/recv()/accept() in a loop until error EAGAIN.
3. epoll_wait() to receive notifications.

(Obviously, the I/O needs to be non-blocking.)

Comment: I found the problem and it actually has nothing to do with epoll.  My application is in C++, and thread pool creation involves a recursive template function with variable arguments and std::bind.  There is some strange sort of race condition occurring, where the resulting std::function object gets cleared and so the threads never enter the epoll_wait() loop.

Comment: @arayq2 Are you sure about that calling order? I've never seen anything epoll related invoke them in that order? I'm having a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885439/epoll-with-edge-triggered-and-oneshot-only-reports-once). The man page suggest that once a fd is re-enabled, if it can meet the criteria of it's flags, it will trigger an event even if ctl is called after wait. Any extra info you can give towards this would be great :)

Comment: I'm not sure in the sense that I can quote chapter and verse from somewhere.  However, the race condition is pretty evident from the existing documentation (which is thin, sigh) and the epoll(7) man page does say that for EPOLLET you need (1) non-blocking fds, and (2) waiting for events only after an I/O op returns EAGAIN.  If you _don't_ use EPOLLONESHOT, the issue of subsequent epoll_ctl( ... EPOLL_CTL_MOD..) calls is moot; if you _do_ use EPOLLONESHOT, the issue is when to call the reactivating epoll_ctl() in view of the race condition.

Comment: Also if you look at the early history of the the epoll system (October 2002 in the linux kernel mailing lists), it becomes clear that edge-trigger semantics are not well understood.  They key point is that the edge trigger  happens at the state transition: from empty to non-empty for reads and from full to not-full for writes.  Thus, to _enable_ the next trigger, the buffers first have to be driven to empty on read/full on write (i.e. EAGAIN).  The issues are subtle enough that one should not expect the same code to work unchanged with LT or ET semantics.